# How do you filter by campaign from the volunteer listing page in civivolunteer?

Tags: civivolunteer, civicampaign

On the regular volunteer listing page (/civicrm/vol/#/volunteer/opportunities) is there a way to filter by campaign like there is within Manage Volunteer Projects?

I'd like to be able to filter within the URL with campaignid or something like that.

In our case, we have a volunteer event that happens at multiple locations with different and different opportunities at each location.  All are on the same day and all are related to one theme.  I'd like to be able to link to just those opportunities in a list.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure the code needs to be modified a little bit to allow you to do it by URL param. Shouldn't take but an hour or two.